# Why is Music Player deleting my music?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, music, music-player, mp3, delete

I recently installed a new SD card in my phone, so I moved all of my music from my phone to my SD. After I moved my music, I noticed that all of my soundtracks were corrupted. Each of them only had about 5 songs and I couldn't play them. I followed [the instructions here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/189180-transfer-my-music-phone-sd-card.html), deleted my Music Player's application data, restarted my phone, etc., and then my soundtracks were completely gone.

Alright, something must have happened during the copy right? So I copy my soundtracks back to my phone, try to open them in my file browser, and it says:

```
Sorry, the player does not support this type of audio file
```

For mp3s that I was playing just yesterday.

So I restart my phone again, and what happens? **My files aren't even there.** Soundtrack folder is empty.

Anyone have any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: That looks very much like a faulty SD card, doesn't it? I'd suggest you put it in your PC and test it thoroughly with a badblocks program.

Comment: Any non-Linux suggestions?

Comment: On Windows, if you right-click on the SD card "drive" and click **Properties**, there's a button in there somewhere. I don't know how to do it on Mac OS.

Comment: Good, then I'll run it when I'm on my Windows box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a bad SD Card. Insist doing that over and over again, with sound files and movie files as well.

Comment: I received it yesterday from an individual vendor on Amazon, so maybe it is a dodgy SD.

Comment: Do not trust them anymore... buy from official store, it is expensive but you will not have any surprises

Comment: Agreed, I'm probably going to try returning it tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not specifically to do with your SD Card.

Did you have songs in a play list?

I find my music is fine unless I add it to a play list, if I do tracks get deleted.

Comment: I believe I had one album that I was listening to at the time which was still getting deleted, but yes, the majority of the music I was listening to was on a playlist. I haven't had the problem since I got my new SD card, so I think that was it.