# Music only plays for a second and then ends?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sd-card, music, music-player, mp3

When I successfully copy my music to my SD card, each song only plays for a second and then continues onto the next song. I was able to remedy this by copying each song over individually, but obviously this is untenable in the long-run. Might this be an issue with my new SD, am I copying too fast, or what else might it be?

I was able to replicate this for skipping to the center of a song. I can't hear an entire second, but it does seek to the center of the song and play a bit of it. If I try to go back to the beginning of the song after every skip, the Music Player eventually crashes.

For any of the mp3s with these issues, [if I restart my phone it deletes these songs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54813/why-is-music-player-deleting-my-music).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious explanation is that the file is incomplete: there's only a small fraction of the file there, or only the first section of the file is readable. Given that the symptoms you report in your other question point to SD card failure, that seems the most likely cause for this too.

If this is a different SD card, it could be that the card itself isn't at fault: rather, whatever you're using to copy files to the card could be corrupting the filesystem, or a dodgy USB connection to a card reader could be interrupting file transfers.

Comment: On some files I could fast forward halfway through the song and it would do the same thing, play a second or so and then move onto the next file. The transfer cable is only a few months old, though I'll try to pick up a new one to compare. I'm using MTP to transfer my files through my phone onto my SD. How reliable is that protocol?

Comment: If you can skip to and play any second of the song this way, not just the beginning, that doesn't sound like an incomplete file. You should hold off replacing the cable until someone has a better explanation.

Comment: Yes, I was just able to replicate it and I can't hear an entire second, but it does seek to the center of the song and play a bit of it. If I try to go back to the beginning of the song after every skip, the Music Player eventually crashes.

Comment: @NobleUplift Edit this information into your question. Then others are more likely to see it and propose a new answer. Right now, people will probably assume my answer is correct, without reading the comments at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The song worked fine in iTunes, but not in Google Music. The song has an audio glitch in it from recording it from a burned CD, and that is around the spot where the song skips. It's not the MP3 or the song; it's something about Google Music doesn't like the song.

My work around: I made an AAC version in iTunes, uploaded that, and it worked. So my original mp3 must have been glitchy.

Answer (score 1):

An incomplete songplay is mostly due to the corrupt file which you have downloaded. Although it may show around 7 MB for a file, if the file is corrupt, then it won't play any part of it, or in some cases, just plays the start and skips to the next.

**What exactly a corrupt file is**

A corrupt MP3 file means that some audio bits and tunes are missing or contain some bugs. The MP3 player usually plays these bits if all are there in the proper order. If some bit of data is missing, then it simply skips to the next track.

The corruption of the file can be judged by the amount of file that is playable. If you can only play the start, then the whole MP3 is corrupt. It is a waste of trying because sometimes you could get only to the middle and later by default, it skips.

**Detect a corrupted MP3 or MP4 file:**-

The best way to check a corrupted file is to do a simple fast forward (don't do a 4x fast forward for you will not know when the file is fast forwarded very fast) till the end of the file. In fast forward, it will skip to the next available data point. As you are able to only fast forward till the middle, the remaining portion of the file is missing/corrupt. If fast forwarding jumps directly to the last, then the whole song is corrupt and needs to be deleted.

For an MP4 file, when the video turns pixelated during a fast forward instead of the smooth audio/video, then that video is corrupt. A complete video plays the audio and video with ease even if you fast forward.

If the file is partially or completely corrupt, you have to delete it because a corrupt file will never play completely.

**How to avoid a corrupt file**

1. Always download files from a reputable source. Some sites don't have proper files, which many fall trap to. If you download from good sources, then you will not have that issue at all. (My suggestion is to avoid using free downloads as far as possible as it's against the law-piracy issues and also you got cheap audio with these kinds of issues)
2. There are some download managers that check for the link and file before downloading. If the link or file is missing/corrupt, then you can avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this on my default Android music player, then I got a clue to the problem.

On another player, there was a setting that said "show music less than 60 seconds" that was turned off.  Well, my music is all around 3 minutes, but not showing up. I changed this setting, and then all the music was listed and played fully.

So there must be something in the music file about length that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Simple solution, use Samsung Music app. Google apparently doesn't like it if your music library was not purchased from them. I have an extensive library of music ripped from my CD's etc. that work fine on any other music player.

Comment: Yeah, I had to use Samsung Music to generate all of my playlist files otherwise my WMP playlists don't convert to M4U.

Answer (score 0):

Today I solved this: it fully depends on the embedded picture inside the MP3 file.

Please note: the MP3 files are not corrupted!
Just the picture file is reader-unfriendly (tested with 2 different readers, and both had the same problem).

So, delete the embedded pictures, or change them with a smaller or different version (with a simple batch process), and it will be OK.

Answer (score -2):

When you transfer music files, do not transfer multiple files at the same time.

Comment: Steve, can you give some background on your argument so it can be understood? I *assume* you're talking about limitations on MTP here – but without some more details I cannot be sure.

Comment: Not only that, this is untenable for 99% of people who listen to music. MTP takes forever to startup and shutdown copy processes, and you can only have one copy process going at a time. Copying one file at a time would take **years** for a sizeable library.